# Passing values to class

Tags: python, oop

I have this abstract class in Python:

```
class TransactionIdsGenerator(object):

  def getId(self):
      raise NotImplementedError
```

And this class that implements:

```
class TransactionIdsGeneratorGeneric(TransactionIdsGenerator):

  INI_FILE = '/platpy/inifiles/postgres_config.ini'    
  __dbManager = None

  def __init__(self):
     TransactionIdsGenerator.__init__(self)

  def getId(self):
     _ret = None
     _oDbManager = self.__getDbManager()
     if _oDbManager.execQuery("select nextval('send_99_seq');"):
         _row = _oDbManager.fetchOne()
         if _row is not None:
             _ret = _row[0]
     return _ret

  def __getDbManager(self):
     if self.__dbManager is None:
        self.__dbManager = PostgresManager(iniFile=self.INI_FILE)

     return self.__dbManager
```

And in other file i have the instance of the class:

```
  def __getTransactionIdsGenerator(self, operatorId):
      _ret = TransactionIdsGeneratorGeneric()
      return _ret
```

Is some way to pass the varibale operatorId to the instance, so i can use in the method **getId** in the class?

Thanks!

Comment: BTW, you probably don't need all those ugly double-underscore names...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to pass it as an argument to `__init__`. (Note that in your current code, you don't even need to define `TransactionIdsGeneratorGeneric.__init__`, since the only thing it does is call the parent's `__init__`.)

```
class TransactionIdsGeneratorGeneric(TransactionIdsGenerator):

    INI_FILE = '/platpy/inifiles/postgres_config.ini'    
    __dbManager = None

    def __init__(self, opid):
        TransactionIdsGenerator.__init__(self)
        self.opid = opid
```

Then when you instantiate the class:

```
def __getTransactionIdsGenerator(self, operatorId):
  _ret = TransactionIdsGeneratorGeneric(operatorId)
  return _ret
```

The key is that the child class's `__init__` doesn't need to have the exact same signature as the parent's, as long as you make sure the correct arguments are passed to the parent when you call it. This isn't entirely true if you are making use of `super`, but since you aren't, I'll ignore that issue. :)